# how to mark an sqlite transaction as complete in phonegap

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I have the following code:

```
  db.transaction(
    function runQuery(tx) {
      tx.executeSql(
        'delete from meetings where id='+id
      );
      log('delete from meetings where id='+id);
    },
    function(e) {
      log('failed to delete from database: '+e.code);
    },
    function() {
      log('meeting deleted from db: '+id);
      setTimeout(callback, 1);
    } 
  );
```

in the callback, I query the meetings table, and the row I've just deleted is still there. this is whether the timeout is 1, 1000, or whatever.

how do I tell phonegap to please close the transaction so the database is properly in sync?

Comment: if I try add tx.executeSql('commit'); to the runQuery function, I get an error "not authorized" from sqlite

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem, this worked for me. http://osdir.com/ml/phonegap/2012-12/msg00429.html

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql("Delete FROM myTable where id=?",[1]);}, errorDeleteCB,successDeleteCB);
```

Only real difference I am seeing is the using of the ? and [1]